# Бинарная сериализация COM-объектов

Tags: c#, массивы, сериализация, com

Как правильно перевести в массив байт COM-объект и/или объекты, к классам которым нельзя получить доступ и поставить им атрибут `Serializable` (например, из сторонних библиотек)?

Answer (score 1):

Например надо сериализовать следующие классы:

```
class SampleClass1
{
    public int SampleField1 { get; set; }
    public string SampleField2 { get; set; }
    public SampleClass2 SampleField3 { get; set; }
}

class SampleClass2
{
    public int SampleField1 { get; set; }
    public string SampleField2 { get; set; }
}
```

Вариант 1:

```
class Serializer1
{
    [Serializable]
    private class SampleClassProxy : ISerializable
    {
        public readonly SampleClass1 Obj;

        public SampleClassProxy()
        {
            Obj = new SampleClass1();
        }

        public SampleClassProxy(SampleClass1 obj)
        {
            Obj = obj;
        }

        public SampleClassProxy(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        {
            Obj = new SampleClass1() {
                SampleField1 = info.GetInt32("SampleField1"),
                SampleField2 = info.GetString("SampleField2"),
                SampleField3 = new SampleClass2() {
                    SampleField1 = info.GetInt32("SampleField3.SampleField1"),
                    SampleField2 = info.GetString("SampleField3.SampleField2")
                }
            };
        }

        public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        {
            info.AddValue("SampleField1", Obj.SampleField1);
            info.AddValue("SampleField2", Obj.SampleField2);
            info.AddValue("SampleField3.SampleField1", Obj.SampleField3.SampleField1);
            info.AddValue("SampleField3.SampleField2", Obj.SampleField3.SampleField2);
        }
    }

    public static void DoWork()
    {
        var obj = new SampleClass1() {
            SampleField1 = 1,
            SampleField2 = "2",
            SampleField3 = new SampleClass2() {
                SampleField1 = 3,
                SampleField2 = "4"
            }
        };

        var proxy = new SampleClassProxy(obj);

        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        var bytes = Serialize(formatter, proxy);
        var proxy2 = Deserialize(formatter, bytes);
        var obj2 = proxy2.Obj;
    }

    private static byte[] Serialize(IFormatter formatter, SampleClassProxy obj)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream()) {
            formatter.Serialize(stream, obj);
            return stream.ToArray();
        }
    }

    private static SampleClassProxy Deserialize(IFormatter formatter, byte[] bytes)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes)) {
            return (SampleClassProxy)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

Вариант 2:

```
class Serializer2
{
    private class SampleClass1Surrogate : ISerializationSurrogate
    {
        public void GetObjectData(object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        {
            var sampleClass = (SampleClass1)obj;
            info.AddValue("SampleField1", sampleClass.SampleField1);
            info.AddValue("SampleField2", sampleClass.SampleField2);
            info.AddValue("SampleField3", sampleClass.SampleField3);
        }

        public object SetObjectData(object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context, ISurrogateSelector selector)
        {
            var sampleClass = (SampleClass1)obj;
            sampleClass.SampleField1 = info.GetInt32("SampleField1");
            sampleClass.SampleField2 = info.GetString("SampleField2");
            sampleClass.SampleField3 = (SampleClass2)info.GetValue("SampleField3", typeof(SampleClass2));
            return sampleClass;
        }
    }

    private class SampleClass2Surrogate : ISerializationSurrogate
    {
        public void GetObjectData(object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        {
            var sampleClass = (SampleClass2)obj;
            info.AddValue("SampleField1", sampleClass.SampleField1);
            info.AddValue("SampleField2", sampleClass.SampleField2);
        }

        public object SetObjectData(object obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context, ISurrogateSelector selector)
        {
            var sampleClass = (SampleClass2)obj;
            sampleClass.SampleField1 = info.GetInt32("SampleField1");
            sampleClass.SampleField2 = info.GetString("SampleField2");
            return sampleClass;
        }
    }

    public static void DoWork()
    {
        var obj = new SampleClass1() {
            SampleField1 = 1,
            SampleField2 = "2",
            SampleField3 = new SampleClass2() {
                SampleField1 = 3,
                SampleField2 = "4"
            }
        };

        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        var surrogateSelector = new SurrogateSelector();
        surrogateSelector.AddSurrogate(typeof(SampleClass1), new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.All), new SampleClass1Surrogate());
        surrogateSelector.AddSurrogate(typeof(SampleClass2), new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.All), new SampleClass2Surrogate());
        formatter.SurrogateSelector = surrogateSelector;

        var bytes = Serialize(formatter, obj);
        var obj2 = Deserialize(formatter, bytes);
    }

    private static byte[] Serialize(IFormatter formatter, SampleClass1 obj)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream()) {
            formatter.Serialize(stream, obj);
            return stream.ToArray();
        }
    }

    private static SampleClass1 Deserialize(IFormatter formatter, byte[] bytes)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes)) {
            return (SampleClass1)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но попробовать его я не могу по двум причинам: во-первых, объект содержит довольно много свойств, а, во-вторых, некоторые свойства доступны только для чтения или только для записи, либо вообще не являются публичными. ввиду этого я не имею возможности писать и читать некоторые свойства. есть ли другой способ? возможно, с использованием каких-либо сторонних библиотек?

Comment: Ну достучаться до приватных полей вроде можно, но во первых это большое фи, во вторых для COM объекта это не пойдет. Проблема которую вы описали на самом деле не проблема. Вам не обязательно сериализовать объект прям по байтно. Вам нужно сохранить состояние объекта по тем свойствам которые можно читать, и восстановить его по тем свойствам которые можно писать. И совсем не обязательно что они будут один к одному. И не обязательно использовать только свойства, методы тоже могут менять/предоставлять состояние объекта

Comment: а есть ли способ, который подойдет для COM-объекта?

Comment: Если у COM-объекта нет встроенной бинарной сериализации то нет.